# How to detect if the USB device is conected to 3.0 port or 2.0port in windows service using win32 apis

Tags: windows, winapi, service, usb, port

I have written a window service using c++ with win32 apis, which will notify whenever USB device is connected to computer,using **SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT**.

Suppose my computer has both USB3.0 and USB2.0 port, How would Service came to know whether device is connected to 3.0 or 2.0 port using this machanism ?

Kindly help me to solve this problem.

Comment: The information is almost certainly available with WMI (get the `Win32_PnPEntity` for the device, and look at the associated objects to see how it is connected). But likely to have different device identifiers for every different USB 3 controller.